# Unable to clear browser's cache

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, browser-cache

I have to disable the back button after logging out from my web site. I am using some header meta tags to clear browser's cache but unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the browser catche throw this code .

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

Or you can use CakeResponse::disableCache() 
like this

```
<?php
        public function search() {
        // do something.
            $this->response->disableCache();
       }
```

Or another idea you can use `clearCache()`, possibly automatically in a model afterSave callback:

```
function afterSave($created) {
    clearCache();
}
```